# How to change an element of a list in python, without just reassigning the entire list

Tags: python, arrays

```
a_list = [1,2,4]
```

How to change `a_list` to

```
a_list = [1,2,3]
```

without just reassigning it by doing

```
a_list = [1,2,3]
```

I just want the last element changed. Do I have to use a for loop or is it just not possible?

Comment: `list[len(list) - 1] = 3`? or maybe the more pythonic `list[-1] = 3`?

Comment: Do not use `list = ....` that hides the `list()` built in. You can access lists by index: `mylist[-1] = 3` will change the last value to 3. `mylist[2] = 3` will change the 3rd element as well (0-based indexing). Do some tutorials - this is really basic python stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Python datastructures are introduced in the 3rd chapter of the python.org documentation / tutorial.

Lists are introduced [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).

> ```
> squares = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
> ```
>
> Like strings (and all other built-in sequence types), lists can be
> indexed and sliced:
>
> ```
> squares[0]  # indexing returns the item
> > 1
>
> squares[-1] # indexing from the back
> > 25
> ```
>
> [ ... snipp ...]
>
> Unlike strings, which are immutable, lists are a mutable type, i.e. it
> is possible to change their content:
>
> ```
> cubes = [1, 8, 27, 65, 125]  # something's wrong here: 4 cubed is 64
>
> cubes[3] = 64  # replace the wrong value
> ```

More methods applicable to lists are handled [in chapter 5 of the python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)